# Is there a way to commit connection with timeout in JDBC connection with PostgreSQL driver?

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-9.5

I am using a PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

I am looking for a way to call Connection.commit() with a timeout. Also should I even do this or not?

Comment: Why do you think you need that. A `COMMIT` usually takes hardly any time, so it's unlikely you'd run into a timeout to begin with. Btw: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: according to my thought as COMMIT is an IO operation it can take time due to network problems and my COMMIT can get stuck. Also when you said postgres 9.5 is not supported , any relation with COMMIT thing , can you explain it a bit more

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name according to my thought as COMMIT is an IO operation it can take time due to network problems and my COMMIT can get stuck. Also when you said postgres 9.5 is not supported , any relation with COMMIT thing , can you explain it a bit more